# Случайная выборка значения массива, но с приоритетом

Tags: php, случайные-числа

Допустим, есть такой массив:

```
$priority = Array(1, 3, 1, 2, 1, 1);
```

**Задача №1:** Сделать случайную выборку, но с приоритетом. Чем выше приоритет, тем ***ниже*** шанс выборки.

**Задача №2:** Сделать случайную выборку, но с приоритетом. Чем выше приоритет, тем ***выше*** шанс выборки.

Comment: Приоритет чего, ниже/выше шанс чего? "Ниже шанс выборки" - это означает, что выборка случайного элемента может случиться, а может не случиться вообще.

Comment: @Fike, "значения массива" :) Читайте внимательнее

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://ideone.com/9MYHDi

> Priority: 0.000000, inversed: false, result: 4960/10000
> Priority: 0.500000, inversed: false, result: 6547/10000
> Priority: 1.000000, inversed: false, result: 10000/10000
> Priority: 0.000000, inversed: true, result: 5004/10000
> Priority: 0.500000, inversed: true, result: 3314/10000
> Priority: 1.000000, inversed: true, result: 0/10000

Насчет проверок (входит ли priority в диапазон 0..1 / есть ли значение в массиве / есть ли в массиве значения кроме указанного) не парился, их надо будет добавить.